# SOAP/HTTP + WSDL as a contract. What about JAX-WS?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I'm a newbie to webservice, and I've read [this chapter](https://today.java.net/today/2003/11/05/ch4SOAP.pdf) (and some other articles) to get an idea about SOAP. Sad, I couldn't find the next chapter about WSDL in java.net.

Anyway, let's suppose I need to implement **SOAP 1.1/HTTP 1.1.**

The used "contract" to exchange information is **WSDL**.

So, in order to create webservices provider :

1. What would be the role of **JAX-WS**?
2. Would it be needed or is it an **alternative** to **WSDL**?
3. If needed, shall we combine it with ( SOAP/HTTP + WSDL)?
4. What would be the role of JAX-WS in this combination?
5. Could it be replaced by JAX-RPC (or by something else)?
6. Is JAX-WS cross-platform or only **specific to Java**?
7. If moving to another platform, such as **C or C++ or Python**, would we be able to use JAX-WS if needed to be combined?
8. Talking C#,.Net... Is JAX-WS similar to WCF?

Thank in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

SOAP and HTTP are message protocols. JAX-WS is the implementation in java for generating these messages. It handles all the low level details of converting java objects to SOAP messages, generating java classes based on WSDL and XSDs. JAX-WS is used for creating SOAP based as well as Rest based messages. It is the underlying technology that handles the messages on both client and server side. JAX-WS implementation is based on WSDL and SOAP standards. It is java specific.

I am not aware of what WCF is.

Comment: I upvote! Thank you a lot for this awsome answer. Do you have any idea about similar implementations to JAX-WS in C, C++ and Python, especially in server side?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with these languages

Answer (score 1):

```
SOAP 1.1/HTTP 1.1.
```

SOAP(XML based Message protocol) over HTTP(Transport Protocol)

```
The used "contract" to exchange information is WSDL
```

Everyone wants to define their own way and framework to describe their webservice. So Microsoft has created contracts for WCF framework.The content of the WSDL document defines the contract of the web service for ex. service, data, fault, message contracts. RIP developers.

```
What would be the role of JAX-WS?
```

JAVA API for XML based web services. Use to create soap based webservice provider. It uses annotations.

```
Would it be needed or is it an alternative to WSDL?
```

JAX-ws is a framework or API.It is an alternative to WCF, you can say not WSDL. WSDL is a document which describes your webservice in XML format.

```
If needed, shall we combine it with ( SOAP/HTTP + WSDL)? 
What would be the role of JAX-WS in this combination?
```

JAX-WS can implement SOAP/HTTP based webservice. USing JAX WS, you can generate WSDL which will describe your defined service implementation.

```
Could it be replaced by JAX-RPC (or by something else)?
```

yes, JAW-RS would also work.

```
Is JAX-WS cross-platform or only specific to Java?
```

JAX_WS is only specific to java. But you can design/implement webservice using JAX-ws which would be cross-platform.

```
If moving to another platform, such as C or C++ or Python, would we be able to use JAX-WS if needed to be combined?
```

You can use jax ws implemented webservice provider to interact with any other language based webservice client.

```
Talking C#,.Net... Is JAX-WS similar to WCF?
```

JAX-WS, WCF both are framewrok to implement webservice in java, .net respectively.

Note: You are quite confused between language, framework, protocol, implementation methods etc. Your questions are very ambiguous. Keep Learning.